# Two CQL Filter not working on a layer

Tags: javascript, wms, layers, cql-filter, cql

I have wms layers like:

**LAYERS=layer1,layer2&CQL_FILTER=(type=10);INCLUDE**

it works fine but when I add another filter with 'and' operator to layer 1 it does not show on map. I am adding second filter like:

**LAYERS=layer1,layer2&CQL_FILTER=(type=10 and range='20_100');INCLUDE**

result returns text/html instead of png.

Here is my loadWMS function:

```
loadWMS: function (index, layerNames, cqlFilters, opacity, styles) {
        var customParams = [
            "FORMAT=image/png",
            "LAYERS=" + layerNames,
            "CQL_FILTER=" + (cqlFilters ? cqlFilters : "include"),
            "SRS=EPSG:900913",
            "EXCEPTIONS=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_inimage",
            "STYLES=" + (styles && styles.length ? styles : "")
        ];
```

My params:

```
["FORMAT=image/png", "LAYERS=ADR_geo:yatirim_fiyat_adet_ek_all_10_view_all,ADR_geo:lake_sea_river_turkey", "CQL_FILTER=(type=10 AND range ='20_100');include", "SRS=EPSG:900913", "EXCEPTIONS=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_inimage", "STYLES=ADR_geo:yatirim_grid_10_kirmizi,ADR_geo:yatirim_grid_10_kirmizi"]
```

What is wrong with cql_filter?

Edit for @iant : The html is 0 KB. so it comes empty screen. In Geoserver's map preview, the cql filter works like `type=10 and range'20_100'`

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  You appear to have created two accounts which inevitably leads to a frustrating experience for you, potential answerers and reviewers so please follow [these instructions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) ASAP to merge your accounts.

Comment: the html will include the error message that tells you what went wrong, open it and add it to your question. The most likely issue is that you don't have an attribute called `range` or that GeoServer is confused by the format of your string and thinks it is a number.